# Inserting Content Version via Community User in test class Failing

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, contentversion

I think this is very straight forward I just can't figure out the issue behind it.

Error:
: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.: [NetworkId]

The Code:

```
public static ContentVersion createCV2(){
    ContentVersion cv=new Contentversion();
    cv.title='ABC';
    cv.PathOnClient ='test';
    Blob b=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    cv.versiondata=EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    insert cv;
    
    return cv;
}
```

This is the one calling the method:

```
Test.startTest();
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
    accountList = TestDataFactory.createAccount('name', 1, true);
    String accountId = accountList[0].Id;
  
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    contactList = TestDataFactory.createContact(USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_LASTNAME, 1, false);
    contactList[0].AccountId = accountId;
    contactList[0].Email = USER_EMAIL;
    insert contactList;
    String contactId = contactList[0].Id;
    
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    userList = TestDataFactory.createCommunityUser(USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_LASTNAME, contactId, USER_EMAIL, 1, true);
    Test.stopTest();
  
    System.runAs(cmmUser){
       TestDataFactory.createCV2(); 
    }
```

If it is being run as System admin , it works fine. But once run as a community user it is throwing the error...

Comment: Community user might not have access to the Object. You can just query an admin user or create an admin user and use `System.runAs` to run this test case with admin user.

Comment: What object? I am not associating the file to any object and just uploading it. I need to run this case as Community user due to some special scenarios. I am just currently stuck here at these line of code.

Comment: When you upload a file it creates `ContentDocument`, `ContentDocumetLink` and `ContentVersion` object in salesforce.

Comment: it is only failing in test class , it is working fine if tested it in the community and uploading file on the same profile

Comment: Can you share the full test class? Or are you sure only this line throws error?

Comment: Yep I am 100% sure this is the one throwing it. In the test class I just inserted an account , a contact and created a user then that's it.

Then called it . No other logic. involved Would be editing the question now for further information

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Code looks fine, which community profile you are using?

Comment: Community user plus.

Comment: With `Customer Community Plus User` it works fine in my org.

Comment: not quite sure aswell :( why I am having this trouble

Comment: I would suggest to add the network ID as well while inserting content version and supply it in test class via query. (Network.getNetworkId won't get correct ID in test class)